# Magento 2: Email Templates Template Style is not Working

Tags: magento2, css, email-templates, html, magento-2.1.3

In **Template Content** i have put

```
<p class="test">Hi</p>
```

**Template Styles** i have put

```
.test { font-size: 40px;}
```

Then i have clicked on **Preview Template**, but it's not applying.

I like to apply CSS for this template only.

[image]

Comment: How you add your style?

Comment: Didn't get you as mentioned in question

Comment: I added screenshot for same @KhoaTruongDinh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, we need to read here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#non-inline-styles.

For the Non Inline Styles, **they must be in a `<style type="text/css"></style>` tag for them to work**. In your case, we only need to include the header `{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}` in your custom email. Or, we can add the code lines below directly in the custom email:

```
<style type="text/css">
    {{var template_styles|raw}}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: You are a saviour my friend :) +1

Comment: How to add this non-inline style in .phtml?

Answer (score 0):

When switching the HTML editor on/off the  tags get removed. Is there another solution to have Template Styles be included?

Comment: Please add more content for more details