# Email template css styles are being ignored

Tags: email, css, email-templates, styles

I've added these styles in the admin, however only the color style is being applied. Position, left and top styles are ignored. Is there anything else I must add? Why is this happening? Any kind of help would be appreciated[image]

Comment: can you share the frontend code for the css class from dev tools? (Css and html) so we could see if there's some css set there that overwrites your custom one

Comment: > that link is useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153258/magento-2-email-templates-template-style-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
.delivery-date {
    color: red;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 45% !important;
    top: 45% !important;
}
```